# Fetch compare and delete string from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

1. I would like to delete a single string provided by a UILabel in a Custom Cell, from CoreData. So to delete a row from tableview does not work.
2. Also, I would like to check if a specific string is in CoreData value.

For example:

I have an Entity named "Favorites" with an attribute named "services" with a string that I inserted named "micro". I want to delete "micro". Also, I want to check if "micro" (for example) is in strings from attribute "services" and entity "Favorites".

I have tried this:

1.

```
let serString = servico.text

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let contexto:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let entidade = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Favorites", inManagedObjectContext: contexto)
        let pedido = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Favorites")
        pedido.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "service = %@", serString!)
        let p:Favorites? = Favorites(entity: entidade!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            contexto.deleteObject(p!)
```

...but it's not deleting the string "serString"

2.
Tried this:

```
var request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Favorites");
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "services = %s", "micro")
    let results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
    if (results.count > 0) {
        print("exists")        }
    else {
        //Doesn't exist
    }
```

... but gives error in "&error" saying "use of unresolved identifier 'error'"

2(b).

tried also this but crashes the app the output gives

"Printing description of error:
(NSError) error = "out of scope"

(lldb) "

```
let request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:     "Favorites");
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "services = %s", "micro")
do {
let results : [NSManagedObject] = try   context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Favorites]
if (results.count > 0) {
            print("exists")        }
        else {
            //Doesn't exist
        }
        // success ...
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

1. This code finally worked to delete string:

   ```
   let favoriteFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Favorites")
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "services = %@", serv)
       favoriteFetchRequest.predicate = predicate
   do {
      let fetchedEntities = try       context.executeFetchRequest(favoriteFetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]

   for entity in fetchedEntities {
   context.deleteObject(entity)
   try context.save()
   }
   } catch let error as NSError {
   print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
   ```

Any help on 2. ?

Comment: I have an Entity named "Favorites" with an attribute named "services" with a string that I inserted named "micro". I want to delete "micro". Also, I want to check if "micro" (for example) is in strings from attribute "services" and entity "Favorites".

Answer (score 0):

1 . I think that you need something like :

```
       contexto.deleteObject(p!)

        do {
            try contexto.save()
            print("Borrado ")
        } catch _ as NSError {
            print( "Error en delete")

        }
```